# I need help to understand my data and to personnalize Flurry analytics

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I need help to understand my data and to personnalize Flurry analytics.

1. How can I have a view :

- The new user I have acquired on Saturday, if the open the app on Sunday, and again on Monday, and again on Tuesday….
- If I have 54,5 active device/day, and I have 294 sessions / days, it means that some players have launch 5 to more time the app on the same day. Sessions is : they open the app, they close the app,
- How can I go deeper in the analytics, to understand the avg time / device / day, and isolate, while knowing the number of people they launch the app, they desinstall it and it counts 10 seconds of use.
- Because My median session length is 8 seconds, and my Average time / device / day is 3 : 3 minutes, can i go deeper in this analysis ?

[App Activity Dashboard example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYyif.png)

2. [On this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezmOX.png), session frequency, that means that 1 user has launch 9 times the app ? or the opposite, 9 users has launchs it 1 time…

MANY THANKS FOR YOUR HELP !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The new user I have acquired on Saturday, if the open the app on Sunday, and again on Monday, and again on Tuesday….

//Navigate to the retention dashboard. The "Return Rate" metric will show you this. The "cohort" is the number of people who first launched an app on a given day.

If I have 54,5 active device/day, and I have 294 sessions / days, it means that some players have launch 5 to more time the app on the same day. Sessions is : they open the app, they close the app,

//Yes, with those numbers, at least some of your users opened the app more than 5 times.

How can I go deeper in the analytics, to understand the avg time / device / day, and isolate, while knowing the number of people they launch the app, they desinstall it and it counts 10 seconds of use.

//You could create a query in Explorer, and filter out users who only launched a single session within the time frame. You could also try using a session filter for "Duration", and eliminate very short sessions.

Because My median session length is 8 seconds, and my Average time / device / day is 3 : 3 minutes, can i go deeper in this analysis ?

//Looking at the number of sessions per person would help get an idea. In addition, as in the question above, you can filter/dimension over session length, which will let you get a better idea of the number of sessions that are very short, versus longer sessions.

#2: 9 users have launched it once